# Symfony: How to use Data Transformers with a FormFactory?

Tags: php, symfony, addeventlistener, symfony-forms, formbuilder

In my Symfony Application i have a From which contains a lot of checkboxes, radios, textfields and also DateTime Objects.
Everything but the DateTime Objects work fine, but with them i always get the error `"Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string"`
So i wanted to use [this tutorial](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/form/data_transformers.html) to change the datetime object to a string.

---

The thing is i am using a FormFactory and when i use the `addModelTransformer()`-Method like this...

**1st Option:**

```
$form->add($formFactory->createNamed('value', 'date', null, $fieldOptions));
$form->get('value')->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
    function($dateAsDate){
        return $dateAsDate->format('Y-m-d');
    },
    function ($dateAsString){
        return "test"; //TODO: to be changed to make string to date
    }
));
```

...i get the Error `"Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Form\Form::addModelTransformer() "`

---

When i use the builder function outside the Formfactory like this...

**2nd Option:**

```
//$builder->addEventListener Stuff is above

$builder->get('value')->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
   function($dateAsDate){ return $dateAsDate->format('Y-m-d'); },
   function ($dateAsString){ return 'null'; } //TODO: to be changed to make string to date
));
```

...i get the Error `"The child with the name "value" does not exist."`

---

Does anybody have an idea how to make this work?

Comment: That message should not be something to solve by using transformers, most likely is a mapping problem with your entity or how you use the field in your template.

Comment: Default types come with the [necessary transformers](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/494ef421c554a78b38c6779c4b7deb9a20d89923/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/DateTimeType.php#L85), so it's unlikely that transforming is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use any custom Tranformer here.

The [DateType](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html) field handles DateTime objects correctly by itself.
You may want to specify some options like 'format' and 'widget' depending on how you want to render your field, but the default 'input' should work fine with DateTime.
For example :

```
$builder->add('value', DateType::class, [
    'format' => 'y-MM-dd',
    'widget' => 'single_text', // To have a single input text box
    'input' => 'datetime'      // This is the default value
];
```